# How come RxJava uses only ~10 threads when processing asynchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java

Consider the following code, I am trying to get the Observables to run asynchronously.

```
    try {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        Observable
                .from(map.entrySet()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 10)))
                .flatMap(Async.toAsync((Map.Entry<String, Info> entry) -> {
                    // processing work, makes multiple http requests for ref data
                }))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("completed yo...."))
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                .toList()
                .timeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .toBlocking()
                .single()
                ;

        logger.info(now.toString());
        logger.info(DateTime.now().toString());

        saveToFile(gson.toJson(setForRx));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output shows that it uses the same ~10 threads to do processing, how can I increase that?

Sample output:

```
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,524 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-3 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,526 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-6 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,542 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-4 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,546 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-7 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,571 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-2
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,694 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-1 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:20,920 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-8
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,035 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-7 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,039 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-4 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,055 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-5
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,081 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-3 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,094 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-6 
INFO  2015-06-29 15:11:21,118 [rxjava.ConcurrentRxJava] RxComputationThreadPool-2
```

In my executor version, using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 10`, I get size 80 pool. Is that possible with RxJava?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163542/asynchronous-restapis-with-rxjava-jersey2-threading-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toAsync()`, by default, runs on the `computation()` scheduler which has fixed number of threads. There is an overload which takes a scheduler so you should refactor the `Schedulers.from(...)` into a local variable and pass that variable to `toAsync()`.